# Monaco Editor: Manually trigger undo\redo from code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, monaco-editor

I have a React application in which I'm trying to manually call undo\redo from code on an instance of a Monaco editor.
I want to do this so I can perform undo\redo when the editor is not in focus. I've searched the API and did not find a way, help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call [`IEditor.trigger`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.IEditor.html#trigger), and use `undo` or `redo` handlers.

Example, where `editor` implements `IEditor`:

```js
// Undo
editor.trigger("myapp", "undo");

// Redo
editor.trigger("myapp", "redo");
```

---

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/451#issuecomment-305445971

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I don't have access to the project anymore so I can't check whether this works. I'll mark it as the answer because it seems pretty straightforward :)